# How to save projects file in htdocs

Tags: php, xampp, htdocs

I am a php developer. I've been developing projects on a Windows system. Now I have completely switched to Ubuntu. I've installed XAMPP on my Ubuntu 16.04. I am not able to save my web files on htdocs as I used to save them in Windows before. My current default directory is `opt/lampp/htdocs/`. Is there a different way to handle the projects on a Linux system?

Comment: Same answer / solution, just different directory ;)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu and Linux let me find a solution

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to save them in that folder?

Comment: You have to change the permission for your htdocs folder.  just type "    
sudo chmod +777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/"  in a terminal and you will be good to go.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps to get your projects setup:

1. Create a users group called `xamppusers`:

   ```
   sudo groupadd xamppusers
   ```
2. Add yourself to that group:

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G xamppusers $USER
   ```
3. Change the ownership of the `/opt/lampp/htdocs` folder:

   ```
   sudo usermod -R root.xamppusers /opt/lampp/htdocs
   sudo chmod -R 775 /opt/lampp/htdocs
   ```
4. Restart the system
5. Restart `xampp`:

   ```
   sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
   ```

To set up sample webpage:

1. Create a document in `htdocs`:

   ```
   nano /opt/lampp/htdocs/info.php
   ```

   - Add this content to it:

     ```
     <?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
     ```
2. Now in browser go to `localhost/info.php`, and you should see the output of that file.

With that if you have a projects you want to create that would in your case come with a `folder` the place that folder in `htdocs` like you use to on `Windows` and your good to go. From the `xampp dashboard` go to `http://localhost/dashboard/howto.html` for more information on running applications.